# In SwiftUI and macOS how do I copy-and-paste and drag and drop multiple local file URLs into a scroll view

Tags: swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop, copy-paste

In my macOS app I need to allow the user get a list of absolute local file URLs by selecting them from Finder using copy-and-paste or drag-and-drop. I'll filter them by the extension ".raw" and they should go, I think, in an array of URL. My experience using an app that support this suggests that I should implement both. I do know how to code a file-picker but that's not what I want.

I've been using Dr. Google to search but what I have found doesn't come close to illustrate what I need are too complex for me to understand enough to use as a guide.

Here is an example of one from an on-line tutorial that kind of works as a C&P but it's far from what I need.  It also produces this: "CLIENT ERROR: TUINSRemoteViewController does not override -viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: and thus cannot react to catastrophic errors beyond logging them" so it's not really good code.

```
struct DataChooserView: View {
    @State private var username = "@twostraws"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Username", text: $username)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)

            PasteButton(payloadType: String.self) { strings in
                guard let first = strings.first else { return }
                username = first
            }
            .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I'm inexperienced in Swift/SwiftUI but learning.

Comment: I am confused. You say you want to drop URLs into somewhere, but in your code you have a paste button pasting a user name?